# What does "FormData was used before it was declared, which is illegal for const variables" mean?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why I am getting the error that "FormData was used before it was declared, which is illegal for const variables" in my Vue component....

```
<script>
    export default {
    ...
    methods: {
      async sendForm(){
        const FormData = new FormData(); // error occurs here
        await this.$axios.post('/upload', FormData).then(response => {
                console.log(response)
            }).catch(error => {console.log(error)})
      }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have searched for `FormData` elsewhere in the component and there is nothing. This is the only time is it constructed.

Comment: When the system tries to exectue `new FormData()` it searches for the definition of `FormData` scoped only to the current block (because you are using `const`). Since it hasn't been declared anywhere in that block, the only reference it can find is the very variable that you are trying to declare and populate with a new instance of `FormData`. Therefore it says that you are trying to use `FormData` (the right-side of the expression) before it's been declared (the left side of the expression).

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you so a simple change of name on the variable like in NIcholas' answers solves it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're declaring a local variable `FormData`, then any code in this block that refers to `FormData` is referring to that. This includes the right hand side of the line: it's referring to the local variable, not whatever other variable you have in mind. So you're trying to inintialize the variable by `new`ing up that exact same variable, and that would require using the variable before it is initialized which isn't allowed.

The fix is most likely just to use a different variable name

```
const example = new FormData();
```

Comment: God I really wish these errors would makes sense! Thank you for the help, I changed the name of the const to just DataForm and it works fine :)